# When are the eigenvalues returned by numpy.linalg.eig ordered?

Tags: python, numpy

The documentation says of the returned values:

> The eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered...

But every time I use the function they are in decreasing order, which is perfect for my use. I want to know under what circumstances I will have to make sure that I sort them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix to be diagonalized is not Hermitian, the eigenvalues will generally be complex, so that they cannot be sorted at all.

`numpy.linalg.eig` calls `LAPACK` routines, and in `LAPACK` sorting in descending order (when possible, i.e. in the case of real eigenvalues) is '[popular convention](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15734#issuecomment-204553663)'. `numpy` cannot only be linked against the reference `LAPACK` at http://www.netlib.org/lapack/, but also against any other library providing the corresponding linear algebra routines, which wouldn't necessarily have to perform the same or any eigenvalue sorting. `numpy.linalg.eig` doesn't perform any sorting beyond what the Fortran routines in `LAPACK` already perform, hence sorted eigenvalues might not be guaranteed even for Hermitian (including real symmetric) matrices.

Comment: I added a sort routine to my code, just in case. Thank you.